# Programmatically make a call in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

In my Android application I want to make a call as a response to a special SMS. So I created app which listens for in coming messages and make a call because of a particular sms. The application works on emulator as expected but when I'm trying to run application on tab which has Android 4.0.3 it ends calling just after starting the call. Here is the code I have used.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
String msgBody;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
}

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){

                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        }

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(msgBody.equals("CALL")){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "XXXXXXXXXXX"));;
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}    
}
```

I have added following permissions:

```
 READ_SMS
 RECEIVE_SMS
 CALL_PHONE
```

What is the wrong here ? Please help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: can you check the log to see if you are getting any crash? I hope your tablet has modem and supports telephony :)

Comment: `it ends calling just after starting the call.` what ?

Comment: @Sushil : the tablet is receiving SMS, so one could only assume...

Comment: @njzk2 call ended just after the starting the call.

Comment: ohh. msgin works, so modem is present. In any case can make a simple call to confirm :) :)

Comment: everything works fine till disconnected? Did you give a real phone number?

Comment: yes phone number is correct and app shows "call ended" just after trying to dial. This don't end the call in emulator.

Comment: Are you able to make usual calls outside the app?

Comment: Yes I can make calls from the tablet,, even I can make a call using intents on button click,, I'm not sure about whether it is not allowed to start call activity "onReceive",, do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: Grant , Did you have find a solution to your problem ? I'm having the exact same problem and it's annoying as hell.

Answer (score 1):

Create another activity say CallActivity, start this activity from your receiver e.g

```
 Intent i=new Intent();
 i.setClass(context,callActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("number","phone_number");
 i.setFlags(Intent.Flag_Activity_newTask);
 context.startActivity(i);
```

Now in onCreate() method of CallActivity, just launch call phone intent:

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "XXXXXXXXXXX"));;
  startActivity(myIntent);
```